# Recursive Feature Selection Error. "invalid type (list) for variable 'y'" - SVM and KNN

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, feature-selection, rfe

I am running some models on data that has 990 observations with 1023 variables. Since p>n I am needing to do some feature selection. As such, I have chosen to do recursive feature selection. I have partial least squares, K Nearest Neighbors, and Support Vector Machine models. When I run the rfe() function on my PLS model I don't get any errors other than a deprecated tibble warning which I don't think is a big deal. However, when I run the SVM and KNN models I get the following error:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "invalid type (list) for variable 'y'"
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

The warnings are again the deprecated tibble, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where the invalid type is coming from since the PLS runs just fine. Please see my code below:

```
#Recursive Feature Elimination Partial Least Squares
predVars <- names(Training)[!names(Training) %in% c("MOV")]
ctrl <- rfeControl(method = "cv",
                   number = 10,
                   verbose = FALSE,
                   functions = caretFuncs) 
#Partial Least Squares Model
set.seed(1211)
PLS_Model <- rfe(x = Training[,predVars], y = Training$MOV, sizes = c(2:25, 50, 75, 100,
                                                                      125, 150, 175, 200),
                 rfeControl = ctrl, method = "pls", tuneLength = 15,
                 preProc = c("center","scale"), trControl = train.control)
#K-Nearest Neighbors Model
set.seed(1211)
KNNModel <- rfe(x = Training[,predVars], y = Training$MOV, sizes = c(2:25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200),
                  rfeControl = ctrl, method = "knn",tuneLength = 10, preProc = c("center", "scale"),trControl = train.control)

#SVM Model
set.seed(1211)
SVM_Model <- rfe(x = Training[,predVars], y = Training$MOV, sizes = c(2:25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200),
                 rfeControl = ctrl, method = "svmRadial", tuneLength = 15, 
                 preProc = c("center", "scale"), trControl = train.control)
```

Quick note, predVars is a chr[1:1022]. Really appreciate everyone's help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys so I was able to figure this out. For some reason on the KNN and SVM models it worked perfectly fine when I changed out the `x=` and `y=` arguments for a formula based `MOV~.`
The models have now run perfectly.